# ASP.NET Rich Edit

Tags: asp.net

Estou há pouco tempo trabalhando com Visual Studio 2015 e surgiu o seguinte erro quando inseri um componente no código HTML. Acredito que seja um erro bobo por falta de conhecimento, mas não tenho ideia de como resolver.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Conseguiu resolver?

Comment: Apareceu o seguinte erro e estou tentando arrumar: To work properly, DevExpress components require ASPxHttpHandlerModule registered in the web.config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faltou você registrar o prefixo da tag

**Exemplo:**

```
<%@ Register assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxRichEdit.v17.1, Version=17.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxRichEdit" tagprefix="dx" %>
<%@ Register assembly="DevExpress.Web.v17.1, Version=17.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" namespace="DevExpress.Web" tagprefix="dx" %>
```

**Fontes:**

[MSDN @Register](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/c76dd5k1(v=vs.85).aspx)

[DevExpress : How to: Insert RTF text to a document](https://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/119372/ASP-NET-WebForms-Controls/Rich-Text-Editor/Examples/How-to-Insert-RTF-text-to-a-document)

**Adendo:**

> Apareceu o seguinte erro e estou tentando arrumar: To work properly,
>   DevExpress components require ASPxHttpHandlerModule registered in the
>   web.config file

Segundo a referência do documento segue as instruções de como

**IIS (Modo Clássico)**

```
<system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v17.2, Version=17.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" verb="GET"
      path="DX.ashx" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
      <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v17.2, Version=17.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule"/>
    </httpModules>
</system.web>
```

**IIS (Modo Integrado)**

```
<system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v17.2, Version=17.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" verb="GET"
      path="DX.ashx" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
      <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v17.2, Version=17.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule"/>
    </httpModules>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v17.2, Version=17.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" verb="GET" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule"
      path="DX.ashx" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
    <modules>
      <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v17.2, Version=17.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule"/>
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

**Fonte:**
[How to: Manually Register ASPxHttpHandlerModule](http://How%20to:%20Manually%20Register%20ASPxHttpHandlerModule)

Comment: Sim, consegui resolver esse problema do web.config, mas agora estou tentando resolver outro: Não foi possível carregar arquivo ou assembly 'DevExpress.Web.v17.2, Version=17.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a' ou uma de suas dependências. O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado.

Comment: Como você fez a instalação do componente? Você está ciente de que se trata de um produto pago, certo?

Comment: Eu não fiz... Sou novo (estagiário) na empresa... e na área.

Comment: Você escolheu ou pediram para você usar ele?... você precisa do suporte de alguém mais experiente, é melhor você perguntar aí na empresa do que aqui. Mas dê uma olhada nesse link https://documentation.devexpress.com/GeneralInformation/15661/Installation

Comment: Pediram que eu usasse esse componente. Copiei a tag dele e colei onde eu teria colocado um HTML textarea.

Comment: Você precisa adicionar as referências primeiro, pergunte a um colega como fazer a configuração para você usá-lo

Comment: Agora este erro... Controle 'ASPxRichEdit1' do tipo 'ASPxRichEdit' deve ser inserido em uma marca de formato com runat=server. Encontrei na internet que eu deveria pôr 'runat="server"' na tag no RIch Edit, mas já tem isso nele...

Comment: Aí já é outra pergunta, como você conseguiu instalar e corrigiu o o registro do prefixo, marque essa como respondida com a minha resposta ou com uma sua descrevendo como resolveu o problema. Depois crie uma nova pergunta com esse seu segundo erro, mas não esqueça de incluir o código ao invés de só imagens.

Comment: Consegui. Faltou colocar o componente dentro de um form com runat="server" também. <form runat="server">